# How to copy files from a folder tree to a single folder and only the latest files?

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

How to copy files from a folder tree to a single folder and only the latest files using batch commands?

These copies must happen every one hour and avoid overwrite rather than copy only latest files.

Current command:

```
for /R "D:\Logshipping\NDWAnalyzer\" %%f in (*.*) do copy "%%f" "D:\LogShipping1\NDWAnalyzer\"
```

The above command copies every time whole files in the folder rather than I need only to copy the latest - the files which are not present in the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy task using [xcopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx) with parameter `/M` which results in copying only files with archive attribute set and clearing this attribute after copying. The archive attribute is automatically set for a new or modified file.

```
@echo off

rem Check before copying for deletion of files in destination directory
rem which were copied already before and not updated in the meantime, i.e.
rem no archive attribute set anymore on file, but file is also not existing
rem anymore in destination directory. The archive attribute is set temporarily
rem on those files before running xcopy. This helps also in case of renaming
rem a file in one of the source directories which was copied already before
rem with previous name to destination directory as the rename operation does
rem not set archive attribute.

for /R "D:\Logshipping\NDWAnalyzer" %%F in (*) do (
    if not exist "D:\LogShipping1\NDWAnalyzer\%%~nxF" %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +a "%%~F"
)

rem Copy from all directories in D:\Logshipping\NDWAnalyzer all files with
rem archive attribute set (= modified or added since last run) to directory
rem D:\LogShipping1\NDWAnalyzer with clearing the archive attribute after
rem copy and with copying also all attributes including read-only attribute.

for /R "D:\Logshipping\NDWAnalyzer" %%D in (.) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%~fD\*" "D:\LogShipping1\NDWAnalyzer\" /C /H /I /K /M /Q /R /Y >nul
)
```

It is up to you if you want to use first + second loop or just second loop.

With removing first loop it would be possible to delete files in destination directory still existing in a source directory or rename a file in a source directory which was copied already before to destination directory without being copied once again.

For more details on the used commands open a command prompt window and run

- `attrib /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `xcopy /?`

A help is output for each command which should be read to understand the two loops above.